# MySQL grant permission to create new databases and all permissions to new created databases

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, sql-grant

I created a new MySQL user with permission to create new databases and tables. I want also that this user have all permissions on databases he will create but not on at this point existing databases. How can I do this?

Comment: Technically not possible. mysql perms are either "everything" or "explicitly just the the following".  there's no time-based capability, or "new only", etc...